# Connection state was not closed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting crazy of tracking where possibly I get the error. Every time that I will click the Receive button. It gives me an Exception Error that says

> The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is
>   open.

Here's the code behind

```
void GetReceiptNo(int ID)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    //cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ReceiptNo FROM PurchaseOrder WHERE PONo=@PONo";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONo", ID);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            txtReceiptNo.Text = dr["ReceiptNo"].ToString();

        }
    }
    else
    {
        con.Close();
        Response.Redirect("~/PurchaseOrder/MaterialsReceive.aspx");
    }
    if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
}

void UpdateInventory(string itemID, string quantity)
{

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Receiving VALUES (@ItemNo, @Quantity, @Timestamp); " +
        "UPDATE RMInventory SET Available = Available + @Quantity WHERE ItemNo=@ItemNo; " +
        "UPDATE PODetails SET Status = 'Received' WHERE PONo=@PONo AND Status='Process' " +
        "UPDATE PurchaseOrder SET Status = 'Received' WHERE PONo=@PONo AND Status='Processing' " +
        "UPDATE PurchaseOrder SET DateReceived=@DateReceived WHERE PONo=@PONo";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONo", Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemNo", itemID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", quantity);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Timestamp", DateTime.Now);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateReceived", DateTime.Now);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

The error will appear on void UpdateInventory
con.Open()

Comment: is your application using threading in any way? if so, you would be better off letting each call construct its own connection, or using a lock or mutex to ensure two calls do not try to open/close the same connection

Comment: cmd.Connection = con, why is this line commented, currently I do not see any association between Command object and Connection object

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the `using` statement when you are dealing with connections. It will help you dealing with these situations.

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
    con.Open();
    //your code
}
```

And if you are not using the `using` statement(*which is ideally recommended*) then you can put your code inside a try catch and finally block and try to close your connection inside the finally block like this:

```
try   
{   
   con.Open();   
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);   

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
   con.Close();    
 }    
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 }
 finally
 {
    con.close();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should *always* close `con` connection immediately as soon as you have finished with it in your code. Sounds like you try to open the connection where it's *already* open.

[`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) is best way to do it.

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
   // Define your CommandText
   // Add your parameters
   // Execute your query
}
```

You can even use it with your readaer as well. Also don't use `AddWithValue` method. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use [`Add` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add.aspx) overloads to specify your parameter type and it's size.